# Unable to access wordpress dashboard after migrating to new host

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, dashboard, administrator

I have migrated one of my WordPress site to a new host, I copied the full copy of WordPress files to new host with same structure (without changing any folder or root structure) and imported database to new host phpmyadmin, edited wp_config.php as per new credential such as host, user, password etc.

Everything worked fine except unable to access admin dashboard (in other words my login window does not redirect to requested admin page). I did only one change that is I renamed database name (as host forces to have new prefix to database name). I use default `wp_` prefix to my table names, please help me to sort out this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the database go to the `wp_options` and change `home` and `site` URLs with `id` 1 and 2 like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipqPbsuZjVAhVHybwKHQzNC9gQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FChanging_The_Site_URL&usg=AFQjCNFZ_wZ8mdidu9UnZ9vjigRGlsErnw). Then try to access domain.com/wp-login.php instead of domain.com/wp-admin. Then go the settings -> permalinks and click save